# Magento 2.3.1, where's tinymce setup.js?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, tinymce

In magento 2.3.1, installed on aws lightsail using bitnami. I'm trying to disable tinymce from inserting `<p>` tags, and the solution that many agree with is

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396255/1920003

`forced_root_block : '', /* <-- Add this setting */`

to

`js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js`

But there are many setup.js files and none look like the standard setup.js file. I really want to apply this solution because

1. I can't upgrade to newer version off magento, I have 50 extensions that will break
2. I can't disable the wysiwyg, there are none technical users editing the site
3. I believe this will work, when I used to create my own hand written CMSes, I used to face a similar problem and fix it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user hoangnm gave the right answer on my [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/dg3x38/magento_231_wheres_tinymce_setupjs/), more testing is needed but it seems that the file I need to edit is

`lib/web/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/tinymce4Adapter.js`

I added this option on line 206 and the problem seems, at first glance to be fixed, again more testing is needed to verify that.

```
    settings = {
        selector: '#' + this.getId(),
        theme: 'modern',
        'entity_encoding': 'raw',
        'convert_urls': false,
        'content_css': this.config.tinymce4['content_css'],
        'relative_urls': true,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: this.config.tinymce4.plugins,
        toolbar: this.config.tinymce4.toolbar,
        adapter: this,
        forced_root_block: '', /* <-- Add this setting */
```